# Webdriver.io how to select and element that changes based on the number of like elements on the page

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver-io

I want a way to select the udp-address-input field inside of this named-source-add div.  The problem I'm having is udp-address-input-<+id> element has a different number based on how many named sources have been added.  There is always only 1 udp-address-input-<+id> inside of the named-source-add div so I was wondering if I can limit my search inside that div?

```
<div id="named-source-add" class="named-div">

<input type="text" class="table-cell" data-bind="textInput: address, attr: 
{id: 'udp-address-input-'+id, readonly: readonly, required: role() == 
'destination'}" id="udp-address-input-18">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used xpath, only looking for inputs with ids starting with udp-address-input inside of the named-source-add div.

```
//div[@id='named-source-add']//input[contains(@id,'udp-address-input')]
```

And I had to add slashes to get this to work with my javascript webdriverio pageobject like this:

```
udpMulticastAddr:{ get() { return '//div[@id=\'named-source-add\']//input[contains(@id,\'udp-address-input\')]';}},
```